# Bounding sphere stuck in place

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math

I've been trying to make a simple collision system for my 3D game, I'm creating a bounding sphere like this:

```
struct ACollSphr
    {
        glm::vec3* pos;
        float radius;
    };
```

And in the while loop that renders my game, in main, I give them a position like this:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < meshModelMatrices2.size(); i++)
            {
                Ackerfe::ACollSphr tempSphr;
                glm::vec3 *temporary = new glm::vec3(meshRenderer2.getBoundingSpherePos(*meshRenderer2.getMesh()) * glm::vec3(vec[i][12], vec[i][13], vec[i][14]));
                tempSphr.pos = temporary;
                radius = meshRenderer2.getBoundingSphereRadius(*meshRenderer2.getMesh(), *tempSphr.pos);

                tempSphr.radius = radius;

                meshSphr.push_back(tempSphr);




                //std::cout << pos.x << "    " << pos.y << "    " << pos.z << std::endl;
                //std::cout << vec[i][12] << "    " << vec[i][13] << "    " << vec[i][14] << std::endl;
            }
```

where meshSphr is a vector of spheres and meshRenderer2 is the renderer I use for the meshes I'm loading in, basically I get the mesh, pass it to getBoundingSpherePos and get the position of that mesh, then I multiply it by a glm::vec3 made up of the position values inside the model matrix of each mesh and I get the radius after that and put my newly created sphere inside the meshSphr vector (which I clear after using it for the collision checks so it can get repopulated again in the next iteration)

my collision check looks like this:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < meshSphr.size(); i++)
        {

            if (Ackerfe::sphrSphrColl(camera3D.getSphr(), &meshSphr[i]))
            {
                camera3D.changePosition(camera3D.getPosition()+glm::vec3(-5.0f));
            }

        }
```

and my sphrSphrColl function looks like this:

```
bool sphrSphrColl(ACollSphr *first, ACollSphr *second)
    {

        if (fabs((first->pos->x - second->pos->x) * (first->pos->x - second->pos->x) +
            (first->pos->y - second->pos->y) * (first->pos->y - second->pos->y) +
            (first->pos->z - second->pos->z) * (first->pos->z - second->pos->z) < (first->radius + second->radius) * (first->radius + second->radius)))
        {
            //std::cout <<"DISTANCE: "<<std::endl<<glm::length(*first->pos - *second->pos) << std::endl << std::endl << std::endl << std::endl;
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

I'm checking the position of the bounding spheres with a cout in my main while loop and the positions are registered correctly but when I pass them to the sphrSphrColl function it only seems to put a bounding sphere in the origin and that's it.

My question: Any idea why it's doing that? While I do have a mesh in the origin why does it only put the bounding sphere there? it's almost like the pointers aren't getting updated when I pass them in the function

Comment: O.T. Any reason why you made a `ACollSphr::pos` a pointer? I would make it of type `glm::vec3` instead. As it is exposed in the sample code it's "crying" for memory leaks.

Comment: O.T. The usage of `fabs()` in `sphrSphrColl()` looks very strange to me. 1st: Squared values should be positive by definition. 2nd: You have the whole comparison as argument of `fabs()`. A comparison returns `true` or `false` and applying `fabs()` to this appears completely sense-less. I believe you confused the nesting of parentheses but actually there is no need of `fabs()` at all.

Comment: Did you try to debug it step by step for a small sample and with pre-defined values where you can calculate the expected results on paper? This is what I would do in your situation... (Regarding _on paper_ - Of course, a calculator could be used as well.) ;-)

Comment: @Scheff yeah that fabs was there from a previous way I used to make that check that didn't work, I got rid of it now that you made me notice it. Also, I did try using glm::vec3 instead of pointers at some point in time but it didn't really work though I can't exactly remember why, I've been working on this thing for more than a week trying to make it work

Comment: also, I did try to debug it by using a simple bounding sphere fixed in a position and that did work, the problem is always when I try to give it more than 1 bounding sphere in more than a position

Comment: @Scheff the reason I made the pos a pointer is so that I can have a vector containing glm::vec3 which are the positions that I create in my main and then I can just make the bounding sphere pos point at those instead of creating another set of glm::vec3, had to do it this way cause the positions will be moving in the future so I wanted to move the bounding spheres by simply making their pos point at the new positions instead of destroying them and remaking them each time